# How to share an image with text on instagram story on through flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, fluent-nhibernate, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to share an image with text on instagram story through flutter and i have tried various plugins to share but every time i can only share an image but not text.How to do it? Please help.

```
 FlutterSocialContentShare.share(
        imageUrl: playBackNotifier.track.coverImageUrl,
        quote: 'Discovered on @lishashmusic',
        imageName: playBackNotifier.track.name,
      );
```

Comment: show how you have tried

Comment: I have tried many plugins including social share or share plus. One of the example is above.